# How to emit an event from another js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

This is a example of EventEmitter.

```
var events = require('events'); 
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter(); 
emitter.on('someEvent', function(arg1, arg2) { 
    console.log('listener1', arg1, arg2); 
}); 
emitter.emit('someEvent', 'byvoid', 1991);
```

How to separate emitter.on() to another js file?

Comment: byvoid... funny, you could have chosen a better book rather than his.

Comment: Really? I have no idea~ 也許像你一樣嗎?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do, but if you want to go for an event centered programming pattern, you may as well create an EventEmitter.js file, which would look like that :

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var localEmitter = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = localEmitter;
```

Then, you can just access your EventEmitter instance with require('EventEmitter.js').